# android. Send data from class to activity and get result

Tags: java, android, interface, android-activity

I have **Activity1** with expandable list view, which has **custom adapter,**

In that adapter class, i capture onClick event of button within child items of my expandable list view, and i need to pass data about selected child item of expandable list to **Activity2** where user does some choises and i need to get result when it's done, (**when Activity2 is finished**) in adapter class, how it can be realized?

Working in adapter class, i can start Activity2 only in new thread, so **i can't call some StartActivityForResult**...

I hope there is some ways like creating shared variable and using it in anywhere, but don't know how.. so help me please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `OnClickListener` class init it in activity and pass to the adapter. Set it to the buttons in your adapter. After click on a button his listener will fire and do whatever you want. If you need to pass some params simply override `OnClickListener` to get all the params you need.

You can write `onClickListener` like this (example for `ListActivity`, so just change getListView to your `ListView`):

```
private OnClickListener mEditClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getListView().getPositionForView(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: Then add custom method to your adpter which will get the result from Activity2 and do all the stuff. Call this method of adapter in onActivityResult callback of Activity1.

Comment: Well, it's been helpful, now i have done some OnClickListener in Activity1, but i can't pass my groupPosition and childPosition to it, any ideas?

Comment: Thank you very much!!! i just set public vars, gPos and cPos in Activity1, and have updating code for these in getView() in my adapter class, so it's working now :)

Answer (score 1):

In the adapter constructor, take the Context as parameter and save it in class variable.
For example it is saved in `Context callerContext` variable.
Now, in onItemClickListener, write following code

```
Intent i = new Intent( callerContext , Activity2.class );
i.putExtra( "value" , items[position] );
callerContext.startActivity( i );
```

Comment: And how i can get result from Activity2 in that case?

Comment: In Activity2, again put that data in intent, and then again call/set the adapter with Activity2.this context

Comment: i think it's some kind of do - loop without any condition.. activity 2 to activity 1, activity 1 to class, class to activity 2.. etc.. or you suggest create intent for adapter class? like this: Intent i = new Intent(this, adapter.class) from Activity2 ?

Comment: You can compare the variable with null, after getting from intent in Activity2 as well as in adapter

Comment: oh, sorry, yes, in this way, i think it would be working))) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

on button click set startActivityForResult and Set Result from Activity2 that will automatically find in onActivityResult of Activity1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result back from the activity to your normal class, supposed it is a class with a custom adapter within it.

1. you cannot use startActivityForResult because you are not in an activity
2. what I did is that i launched the activity from the class with an intent. Then I calculated or did what I have to. From this activity I send the information to the main class supposed with a method MainActivity.the_method() and in the main activity I changed the custom adapter o did what I have to using the adapter object and calling adapter.getItem(position)

Hope this can give you an idea